# What is the "tag engine server" implementation in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I was reading [this infographic](https://stackexchange.com/performance) about Stack Exchange performance and topology
and I came across this part where it says that there are *"3 TAG ENGINE SERVERS"* that are *"a unique custom, high performance index of Stack Exchange questions"*.

Does anyone have any more information on how this is implemented?

Comment: We have no idea how the damn thing works.

Comment: Each week, we sacrifice the blood of a unicorn to the Tag Engine in a dark ritual. In return, it continues to serve our websites. Past that, it's a black box.

Comment: Until [Marc Gravell](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) answers this, read [this](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2014/04/technical-debt-case-study-tags.html) and [this](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2011/10/assault-by-gc.html)  and [watch this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQp5l-thyIE&feature=youtu.be&t=1548)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Basically it is just a custom server that keeps an in-memory set of pre-indexed data (all questions from all sites) in a way that is particularly amenable to most "show me a set of related questions" searches; it also has a query parser for a DSL and a few optimized strategies for applying our most common searches, and a fallback strategy for the rest. Not as flexible as a sql server or lucene etc, but pretty good at doing  one  thing well. It also obviously has to be able to pull in all changes (add / edit / delete / etc) to all questions in a fairly timely manner, and have some caching and cache-invalidation.

The main other thing it contains is a self-updating core so that we can leave it  running as a windows service (think: daemon), and it will update itself with the latest code without ever seeing a disruption in service (the outer layer spins up a  second copy of the the new code, gets it all working, switches between the two, then decommissions the  old).

Comment: I have also read your blog posts about it and technical debt. Very helpful. The hot deploy with 2 versions of code sounds very complicated to implement by yourself. Is this also custom implementation or is did you use a server feature like tomcat v7 parallel deployment (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment)

Comment: @zpontikas nope; outer service shell deals with network/IO; inner core is hosted app-domain instances in isolated folders

Answer (score 6):

If you want to know a bit more see these posts (warning, I don't actually know how it's implemented, these posts are my attempt at finding out!)

- http://mattwarren.org/2014/11/01/the-stack-overflow-tag-engine-part-1/
- http://mattwarren.org/2015/08/19/the-stack-overflow-tag-engine-part-2/
- http://mattwarren.org/2015/10/29/the-stack-overflow-tag-engine-part-3/