# Technical reason to avoid using a dot (period, FULL STOP) character in a tag name?

Tags: support, tags

The Help page, [*What are tags, and how should I use them?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) states vaguely:

> **How to format tags**

> …

> Avoid punctuation (which can make it difficult to use the tag in a URL)

Does this mean I should not use a [dot/period/FULL STOP/`.`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop) character in my tag name?

Some technical product names use a period. For example, see [this meta page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398779/642706) discussing a tag name for the *java.time* framework.

I do recall being told years ago to delete a tag `java.time` and creating a tag `java-time`. I then volunteered to reassign the tag to dozens of questions. This issue is not that Stack Overflow prevents the creation of a tag with a dot; clearly we can. The issue is whether we *should or should not* use a dot in a tag.

And by the way, I suggest that Help page be edited to be specific about prohibited characters.

Comment: `.`, `+`, and `#` are specially handled and can be used. `-` works normally. Other punctuation should be avoided. The `java.tag` discussion is about merging two tags with the same meaning, not about the punctuation.

Comment: @user4642212 Can you cite a reference about that special handling? I recall FULL STOP in particular being a problem in tag names.

Comment: Can you cite a reference for _that_? There’s [tag:.net] which has no problems.

Comment: No, I cannot cite a reference. That is why I asked this Quesion, to get a clear resolution on this simple issue. So I ask you again for a reference rather than an opinion. I do recall being told years ago to delete a tag `java.time` and creating a tag `java-time` and then volunteering to reassign the tag to dozens of questions. This issue is *not* that Stack Overflow prevents the creation of a tag with a dot, clearly we can. The issue is whether we *should* use a dot in a tag.

Comment: I don’t think this is about the `.`, but about _consistency_. Every Python function or library is tagged `python-*`, every Java function, etc., should be tagged `java-*`, every jQuery plugin is tagged `jquery-*`, even though some of them contain a `.` in actual code.

Comment: @user4642212 I submit there is a *reason* why you are seeing hyphen substituted for a dot in such tag names. Let’s  focus on the Question: Is there a technical reason to avoid a dot within a tag name?

Comment: Regarding the special handling: if you inspect a tag search page for [tag:c++], [tag:c#], or [tag:.net], you’ll find that the C++ questions have the class name `t-cçç`, the C# questions have the class name `t-cñ`, and .NET questions have the class name `t-ûnet`. There’s also an answer mentioning this somewhere on Meta that I’m trying to find.

Comment: Found the answer: [Stack Overflow doesn't highlight some tags (?)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397620/4642212).

Comment: see this list https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298981/158100

Comment: probably also relevant: TagEngine: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296066/what-is-the-tag-engine-server-implementation-in-stack-overflow/296329#296329

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for doing some edits, but all uppercase is the proper case for the official name of a character in Unicode.

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps the issue with URL was compatibility with older browsers, though I've personally never heard about it since older browsers are unsupported anyway. However, for searchability, look like punctuations other than `-` (hyphen) are treated as-is, meaning that the user has to explicitly type the character to include it in the search result, compared to `-` which is basically ignored, e.g. `javat` (without hyphen) also returns `java-time`, but only `java.t` (with dot) returns `java.time`.